# Solving: [ERROR] No compiler installed in your current switch

Tags: gcc, terminal, compiler-errors, ocaml

I am trying to get OCaml up and running on my Mac, but am running into a problem.

I am following the installation instructions detailed [here](https://ocaml.org/docs/up-and-running#up-and-running-with-the-platform-installer). The first steps I took were the following:

1. I installed the binary files (since I did not want to use Homebrew or MacPort)

   ```
   $ bash -c "sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)"
   ```
2. I then created a new switch by typing:

   ```
   opam init
   ```
3. I then run the following to begin to install the platform tools:

   ```
   $ bash < <(curl -sL https://ocaml.org/install-platform.sh)
   ```
4. After this, I attempt to run the command:

   ```
   $ ocaml-platform
   ```

However, here I run into a problem. When I run the above command, I get the following error:

```
ocaml-platform: [ERROR] No compiler installed in your current switch.
```

I am a bit confused here - I do have gcc installed on my Mac and I think the documentation said that for Mac the only requirements were to have Xcode installed, which I also have installed on my Mac.

Am I missing a step here?

Comment: There is no step there that says you should install`opam`? I suspect doing so and not having set up a switch is the problem. Either uninstall `opam`, or run `opam switch create <version>`.

Comment: I would also expect the installer to handle that scenario though, so seems like a bug as well (it is experimental after all).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `opam update` in your terminal. It might be because you didn't update your opam repository.